# Regex.Replace only replaces start of string

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I'm trying to replace a friendly url pattern with a html url notation but due to lack of regex experience I can't figure out why my regex only replaces the first occurence of my pattern:

```
string text = "[Hotel Des Terrasses \http://flash-hotel.fr/] and [Du Phare \http://www.activehotels.com/hotel/]";
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\[(.+)\s*\\(.+)\]", "<a href=\"$2\" target=\"_blank\">$1</a>");
```

How can i make the second pattern be replaced with the HTML markup too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex treats the entire string as a single match. Try using `(.+?)` instead of `(.+)` (both instances).

Comment: This is the correct answer.  (You need to change both `.+`'s)

Answer (score 1):

As an aside note, you might want to consider potential abuse of this.  You should probably perform:

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int pos = 0;

        Regex exp = new Regex(@"\[(.+?)\s*\\(.+?)\]");
        foreach (Match m in exp.Matches(text))
        {
            sb.Append(text, pos, m.Index - pos);
            pos = m.Index + m.Length;

            Uri tmp;
            if(Uri .TryCreate(m.Groups[2], UriKind.Absolute, out tmp))
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("<a href=\"{0}\" target=\"_blank\">{1}</a>",
                    System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(tmp.AbsoluteUri),
                    System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(m.Groups[1])
                    );
            }
        }
        sb.Append(text, pos, text.Length - pos);
```

Note: Not sure of the group indexes, I'd use named groups in the reg-ex.  Have you tried a regex tool like [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm)?

Comment: This isn't the problem.  (`Regex.Replace` replaces _all_ matches)

Comment: Wasn't sure as I normally don't use the static version of the replace, I'll update.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, great idea. But in my scenario not needed as it's not web input.